# Setting the Scrollbar Thumb size

Tags: wpf, slider, scrollbar

I am attempting to work out the algorithm associated with sizing of the WPF Scrollbar thumb element.

The thumb element can be sized using the `Scrollbar.ViewportSize` property, but it in turn is related to the `Scrollbar.Minimum` and `Scrollbar.Maximum` values.

What I have discovered so far is:

For a Minimum and Maximum of **0** and **10**, a ViewportSize of:

0 - Thumb minimum size
5 - Thumb approximately 25% of the available track
10 - Thumb approximately 50% of the available track
100 - Thumb approximately 75% of the available track
1000 - Thumb approximately 90% of the available track
10000 - Thumb fills the available track.

[note: these figures are only from my rough trial and error!]

Ideally I'd like to be able to have an algorithm where given the minimum and maximum values for the Scrollbar I can set the thumb size to be exactly x% of the available track.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot determine the thumb size from just Min and Max. You also need the relative viewport size(how much from the [Min,Max] interval fits in the viewport): thumbSizePercent=Min( 100, 100*ViewportSize/(MaxValue-MinValue))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.track(VS.90).aspx

> thumbSize =
>   (viewportSize/(maximum–minimum+viewportSize))×trackLength

or re-arranging for viewportSize:

> viewportSize =
>   thumbSize×(maximum-minimum)/(trackLength-thumbSize)

You've prob found this already but thought I'd post in case others end up here.

Comment: If you just need relative size: `viewportSize = (maximum - minimum) * p / (1 - p)`, where `p` is between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot: what happens if p=1?

Comment: Here's a doc on how to set the thumb size with examples. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-customize-the-thumb-size-on-a-scrollbar

Answer (score 4):

On my side, I preserved a minimum thumb length because touch inputs require a thumb of a minimum size to be touch optimized.

You can define a ScrollViewer ControlTemplate that will use the TouchScrollBar as its horisontal and vertical ScrollBar.

See UpdateViewPort method for the math.

Sorry, I don't see the use case for explicitly setting the scrollbar thumb to cover a percentage of the track length

```
public class TouchScrollBar : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar
{
    #region Fields

    #region Dependency properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinThumbLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register
        ("MinThumbLength", typeof(double), typeof(TouchScrollBar), new UIPropertyMetadata((double)0, OnMinThumbLengthPropertyChanged));

    #endregion

    private double? m_originalViewportSize;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public double MinThumbLength
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinThumbLengthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinThumbLengthProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public TouchScrollBar()
    {
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private bool m_trackSubscribed;
    void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubscribeTrack();
    }

    private void SubscribeTrack()
    {
        if (!m_trackSubscribed && Track != null)
        {
            Track.SizeChanged += OnTrackSizeChanged;
            m_trackSubscribed = true;
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region Protected and private methods

    #region Event handlers

    #region Dependency properties event handlers

    private void OnMinThumbLengthPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TouchScrollBar instance = d as TouchScrollBar;
        if(instance != null)
        {
            instance.OnMinThumbLengthChanged(e);

        }
    }

    #endregion

    protected void OnTrackSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubscribeTrack();
        UpdateViewPort();
    }

    protected override void OnMaximumChanged(double oldMaximum, double newMaximum)
    {
        base.OnMaximumChanged(oldMaximum, newMaximum);

        SubscribeTrack();
        UpdateViewPort();
    }

    protected override void OnMinimumChanged(double oldMinimum, double newMinimum)
    {
        base.OnMinimumChanged(oldMinimum, newMinimum);

        SubscribeTrack();
        UpdateViewPort();
    }

    protected void OnMinThumbLengthChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubscribeTrack();
        UpdateViewPort();
    }

    #endregion

    private void UpdateViewPort()
    {
        if(Track != null)
        {
            if(m_originalViewportSize == null)
            {
                m_originalViewportSize = ViewportSize;
            }

            double trackLength = Orientation == Orientation.Vertical ? Track.ActualHeight : Track.ActualWidth;
            double thumbHeight = m_originalViewportSize.Value / (Maximum - Minimum + m_originalViewportSize.Value) * trackLength;
            if (thumbHeight < MinThumbLength && !double.IsNaN(thumbHeight))
            {
                ViewportSize = (MinThumbLength * (Maximum - Minimum)) / (trackLength + MinThumbLength);
            }
        }
    }


    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Another way to set the MinWidth or MinHeight of the Thumb is shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613595.aspx

Comment: @Nadzzz: Your code has a number of issues and won't work as expected at all. Most important, you change the ScrollBar's ViewportSize and it will never be calculated again when the number of items in the list changes. This may only work for static data in a static layout, not anything that might change a bit at runtime.

Comment: @Kolky: That example from Microsoft also doesn't work. It throws all kinds of exceptions. I don't know whether it would do the correct thing at all, if it worked. I can't see any MinHeight logic in it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method that will override the thumb minimum width for all `ScrollBar`s. There's 2 important reasons for using this setup.

1) This will not resize the `ScrollBar` `RepeatButton`s. (Why the style overrides `Track`)

2) This will *only* resize the thumbs for `Track` controls that are used in `ScrollBar`s. (Why the `Track` style is contained in a `ScrollBar` style.

```
<!-- Override for all styles -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollBar}}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Track}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <System:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}">48</System:Double>
                <System:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}">48</System:Double>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<!-- Override for a certain control -->
<!-- The ScrollBar Style part in the middle can be safely ommited
if you can guarantee the control only uses Tracks for ScrollBars -->
<SomeControl>
    <SomeControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollBar}}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Track}">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <System:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}">48</System:Double>
                        <System:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}">48</System:Double>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </SomeControl.Resources>
</SomeControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for how to set a minimum height for the scrollbar thumb:

From Ian (da real MVP) [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a7f71bd-d64f-4341-9b7f-9db90afa6e8b/minheight-on-scrollbar-thumb?forum=wpf):

```cs
scrollBar1.Track.ViewportSize = double.NaN;  
scrollBar1.Track.Thumb.Height = Math.Max(minThumbHeight, DataScrollBar.Track.Thumb.ActualHeight);
```

Or you know, add 100+ lines of xaml code cause omgDATABINDING!!1!

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar thumb size for UWP:

```
    static void SetViewportSize(ScrollBar bar, double size)
    {
        var max = (bar.Maximum - bar.Minimum);
        bar.ViewportSize = size / (max - size) * max;
        bar.IsEnabled = (bar.ViewportSize >= 0 &&
            bar.ViewportSize != double.PositiveInfinity);
        InvalidateScrollBar(bar);
    }

    static void InvalidateScrollBar(ScrollBar bar)
    {
        var v = bar.Value;
        bar.Value = (bar.Value == bar.Maximum) ? bar.Minimum : bar.Maximum;
        bar.Value = v;
    }
```