# How to programmatically change ScrollBar Foreground/Background properties of a ListBox ScrollBar?

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollbar

I finally made the switch to WPF from winforms, even though I rarely even use winforms. Added a `ListBox` control and this XAML code in the Main Window to change the color of its `ScrollBar` `Foreground`/`Background`.

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarColor" TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF343434" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF8E9195" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

How would I go about changing these properties programmatically? Also how about in another window and with the ability to alter them at runtime? I've tried numerous approaches using `FindResource` and `Resources.FindName` using the key as the arg but no luck so far. Any point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Doing this in WinForms would be a bit more time-consuming and more familiar for me, but I'm trying to make that switch.

Comment: If you approach WPF like WinForms you are in for a world of pain. Use xaml when possible as pesky code behind will only bite you back. That style that you have there has a key which needs to referenced through xaml. [Here is an SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487285/custom-listbox-scrollbar-style-issue). Good luck

Comment: Ya I'm beginning to realize that lol and thank you for that link, that question was the first I was brought to. It was a bit much xaml so i skimmed over the comments more than the code lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I go about changing these properties programmatically?

Controls can have multiple states like *Disabled*, *Mouse Over* or *Pressed* which all have different visual representations. Have a look at the style and template documentation for `ScollBar`.

- [ScrollBar Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/scrollbar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

You can in theory get the `ScrollBar` of a `ListBox` in code by searching all children like this:

- [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/636383/6181599)

In your code you can get the `ScrollBar` and apply a different color to it, but this will not work for all the different states. Of course you could create a custom style to handle all states and assign it here, too.

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ... />
```

```
var scrollbar = FindChild<ScrollBar>(MyListBox, null);
scrollbar.Background = Brushes.Red;
scrollbar.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
```

However, I **do not recommend** using code here. Instead you could [extract the default style and control template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825030/6181599) of `ScrollBar` using Blend or Visual Studio. In this copy of the style, you could change the default colors to your needs (look for `SolidColorBrush`es in the code below). Then create a `ListBox` style based on the default style and add the *implict* styles of the `ScrollBar` to its `Resources` section. That is it, the styles for the `ScrollBar` will be applied automatically to the `ListBox` scrollbar.

If you do not want the `ListBox` style to be applied to all `ListBox`es in scope, add an `x:Key` to make it explicit and reference it manually using `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
   <Style.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
         <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate>
                  <Rectangle Margin="2"
                             StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                             StrokeThickness="1"
                             Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Background"
                       Color="#F0F0F0" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Border"
                       Color="#F0F0F0" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Glyph"
                       Color="#606060" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Static.Thumb"
                       Color="#CDCDCD" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Background"
                       Color="#DADADA" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Border"
                       Color="#DADADA" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph"
                       Color="#000000" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb"
                       Color="#A6A6A6" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Background"
                       Color="#606060" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Border"
                       Color="#606060" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb"
                       Color="#606060" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph"
                       Color="#FFFFFF" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Disabled.Background"
                       Color="#F0F0F0" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Disabled.Border"
                       Color="#F0F0F0" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph"
                       Color="#BFBFBF" />
      <Style x:Key="RepeatButtonTransparent"
             TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
         <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                 Value="true" />
         <Setter Property="Background"
                 Value="Transparent" />
         <Setter Property="Focusable"
                 Value="false" />
         <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                 Value="false" />
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                  <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                             Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                             Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="ScrollBarButton"
             TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
         <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                 Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                 Value="1" />
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                 Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                 Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="Padding"
                 Value="1" />
         <Setter Property="Focusable"
                 Value="false" />
         <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                 Value="false" />
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                  <Border x:Name="border"
                          Background="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Background}"
                          BorderThickness="1"
                          BorderBrush="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Border}"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                     <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                       Focusable="False"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                       Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                       SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                  </Border>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                              Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="border"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Background}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                TargetName="border"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Border}" />
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                              Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="border"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Background}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                TargetName="border"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Border}" />
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                              Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                Value="0.56" />
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="border"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Background}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                TargetName="border"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Border}" />
                     </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbVertical"
             TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
         <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                 Value="true" />
         <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                 Value="false" />
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                  <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle"
                             Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Thumb}"
                             Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                             Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                              Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="rectangle"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb}" />
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsDragging"
                              Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="rectangle"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb}" />
                     </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
      <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbHorizontal"
             TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
         <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                 Value="true" />
         <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                 Value="false" />
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                  <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle"
                             Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Thumb}"
                             Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                             Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                              Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="rectangle"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Thumb}" />
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsDragging"
                              Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="rectangle"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Thumb}" />
                     </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
         <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled"
                 Value="false" />
         <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled"
                 Value="false" />
         <Setter Property="Background"
                 Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Background}" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                 Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Border}" />
         <Setter Property="Foreground"
                 Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                 Value="1,0" />
         <Setter Property="Width"
                 Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
         <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                 Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                  <Grid x:Name="Bg"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}" />
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                             Grid.Row="1" />
                     <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineUpButton"
                                   Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"
                                   IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}">
                        <Path x:Name="ArrowTop"
                              Data="M 0,4 C0,4 0,6 0,6 0,6 3.5,2.5 3.5,2.5 3.5,2.5 7,6 7,6 7,6 7,4 7,4 7,4 3.5,0.5 3.5,0.5 3.5,0.5 0,4 0,4 z"
                              Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Glyph}"
                              Margin="3,4,3,3"
                              Stretch="Uniform" />
                     </RepeatButton>
                     <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                            IsDirectionReversed="true"
                            Grid.Row="1">
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                           <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}"
                                         Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                           <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}"
                                         Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.Thumb>
                           <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbVertical}" />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                     </Track>
                     <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineDownButton"
                                   Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"
                                   IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                   Grid.Row="2"
                                   Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}">
                        <Path x:Name="ArrowBottom"
                              Data="M 0,2.5 C0,2.5 0,0.5 0,0.5 0,0.5 3.5,4 3.5,4 3.5,4 7,0.5 7,0.5 7,0.5 7,2.5 7,2.5 7,2.5 3.5,6 3.5,6 3.5,6 0,2.5 0,2.5 z"
                              Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Glyph}"
                              Margin="3,4,3,3"
                              Stretch="Uniform" />
                     </RepeatButton>
                  </Grid>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineDownButton}"
                                      Value="true" />
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineDownButton}"
                                      Value="true" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="ArrowBottom"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph}" />
                     </MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineUpButton}"
                                      Value="true" />
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineUpButton}"
                                      Value="true" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="ArrowTop"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph}" />
                     </MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineDownButton}"
                                      Value="true" />
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineDownButton}"
                                      Value="false" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="ArrowBottom"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                     </MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineUpButton}"
                                      Value="true" />
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineUpButton}"
                                      Value="false" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="ArrowTop"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                     </MultiDataTrigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                              Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="ArrowTop"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph}" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                TargetName="ArrowBottom"
                                Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph}" />
                     </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                     Value="Horizontal">
               <Setter Property="Width"
                       Value="Auto" />
               <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                       Value="0" />
               <Setter Property="Height"
                       Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}" />
               <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                       Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}" />
               <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                       Value="0,1" />
               <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Bg"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}" />
                              <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*" />
                              <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}" />
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                   BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                   BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="1" />
                           <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineLeftButton"
                                         Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"
                                         IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                         Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}">
                              <Path x:Name="ArrowLeft"
                                    Data="M 3.18,7 C3.18,7 5,7 5,7 5,7 1.81,3.5 1.81,3.5 1.81,3.5 5,0 5,0 5,0 3.18,0 3.18,0 3.18,0 0,3.5 0,3.5 0,3.5 3.18,7 3.18,7 z"
                                    Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Glyph}"
                                    Margin="3"
                                    Stretch="Uniform" />
                           </RepeatButton>
                           <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                              <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                 <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}" />
                              </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                              <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                 <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageRightCommand}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}" />
                              </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                              <Track.Thumb>
                                 <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbHorizontal}" />
                              </Track.Thumb>
                           </Track>
                           <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineRightButton"
                                         Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"
                                         Grid.Column="2"
                                         IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                         Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}">
                              <Path x:Name="ArrowRight"
                                    Data="M 1.81,7 C1.81,7 0,7 0,7 0,7 3.18,3.5 3.18,3.5 3.18,3.5 0,0 0,0 0,0 1.81,0 1.81,0 1.81,0 5,3.5 5,3.5 5,3.5 1.81,7 1.81,7 z"
                                    Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Static.Glyph}"
                                    Margin="3"
                                    Stretch="Uniform" />
                           </RepeatButton>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                           <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}"
                                            Value="true" />
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}"
                                            Value="true" />
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="Fill"
                                      TargetName="ArrowRight"
                                      Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph}" />
                           </MultiDataTrigger>
                           <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}"
                                            Value="true" />
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}"
                                            Value="true" />
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="Fill"
                                      TargetName="ArrowLeft"
                                      Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Pressed.Glyph}" />
                           </MultiDataTrigger>
                           <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}"
                                            Value="true" />
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}"
                                            Value="false" />
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="Fill"
                                      TargetName="ArrowRight"
                                      Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                           </MultiDataTrigger>
                           <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}"
                                            Value="true" />
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}"
                                            Value="false" />
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="Fill"
                                      TargetName="ArrowLeft"
                                      Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                           </MultiDataTrigger>
                           <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                    Value="false">
                              <Setter Property="Fill"
                                      TargetName="ArrowLeft"
                                      Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph}" />
                              <Setter Property="Fill"
                                      TargetName="ArrowRight"
                                      Value="{StaticResource ScrollBar.Disabled.Glyph}" />
                           </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

If there are (for whatever reason) nested scrollbars in the `ListBox`, the styles would be applied there, too, since they are implicit. If you run into an issue there,  extract the *full* `ListBox` style and create an explicit style for the contained `ScrollViewer` that you can customize the same way.

> Also how about in another window and with the ability to alter them at runtime? I've tried numerous approaches using FindResource and Resources.FindName [...]

In order to change resources or themes at runtime, you could add the resources in question to a `ResourceDicitonary` and add it to the applicaiton resource dictionary (in `App.xaml`). You have to reference the resources using `DynamicResource`, otherwise they will not be updated when the resources are replaced. Then at runtime you can relace a resource dictionary with another to change styles. See these related questions and answers.

- [WPF: Changing Resources (colors) from the App.xaml during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/786183/6181599)
- [Change theme at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6229724/6181599)

Comment: What if I used a value as {DynamicResource} for BGColor FGColor? What would need to be added in my second window for it to have access to this resource? I probably shouldn't have decided my first WPF attempt, be a winform port.